# How do I get multiple results from different rows in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all the rows of results from my table 'question' where the quiz ID ($currentQuizID) is the same. My code only allows me to get a single row of data from the table, so what should I do?

```
$findQuiz = "SELECT QuizID FROM quiz ORDER BY QuizID DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($user->db,$findQuiz);
$iddata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$currentQuizID = $iddata['QuizID'];

$findQuestions = "SELECT Type, Question, Answer FROM question WHERE QuizID = '".$currentQuizID."'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($user->db,$findQuestions);
$iddata2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
echo $iddata2[0];
echo $iddata2[1];
echo $iddata2[2];
```

Comment: Put them on a while loop.

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
   $questions[] = $rows['type'];
}  add while loop get multiple records.

Comment: @L.Herrera how would I write it?

Comment: @pawansen how would I write it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
   echo $row["Type"]." ".$row["Question"]." ".$row["Answer "]."\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting Quiz id's Use while loop to get multiple records from question's table

```
$findQuiz = "SELECT QuizID FROM quiz ORDER BY QuizID DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($user->db,$findQuiz)
$totalArray = array();

while($iddata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);) 
{
        $currentQuizID = $iddata['QuizID'];
        $findQuestions = "SELECT Type, Question, Answer FROM question WHERE QuizID = '".$currentQuizID."'"; 
        $result2 = mysqli_query($user->db,$findQuestions);
        $iddata2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
        $res['Type'] = $iddata2[0];
        $res['Question'] = $iddata2[1];
        $res['Answer'] = $iddata2[2];
        array_push($totalArray,$res);
 }

 print_r($totalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$findQuestions = "SELECT Type, Question, Answer FROM question WHERE QuizID = '".$currentQuizID."'"; 
$result2 = mysqli_query($user->db,$findQuestions);
$iddata_questions = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $iddata_questions[] = array($row["Type"],
                                $row["Question"],
                                $row["Answer"]);
}

echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($iddata_questions);
echo "</pre>;
```